# Calculating runtime in recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, runtime, divide-and-conquer

Practicing recursion and D&C and a frequent problem seems to be to convert the array:
`[a1,a2,a3..an,b1,b2,b3...bn]` to `[a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3...an,bn]`
I solved it as follows (`startA` is the start of `a`s and `startB` is the start of `b`s:

```
private static void shuffle(int[] a, int startA, int startB){  
        if(startA == startB)return;  
        int tmp = a[startB];  
        shift(a, startA + 1, startB);  
        a[startA + 1] = tmp;  
        shuffle(a, startA + 2, startB + 1);  
    }  

    private static void shift(int[] a, int start, int end) {  
        if(start >= end)return;  
        for(int i = end; i > start; i--){  
            a[i] = a[i - 1];   
        }       
    }
```

But I am not sure what the runtime is. Isn't it linear?

Comment: When you say runtime you mean time complexity, right?

Comment: @Keyser:Yes the `O(f(n))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the time consumed by the algorithm be `T(n)`, and let `n=startB-startA`.

Each recursive invokation reduces the run time by 1 (`startB-startA` is reduced by one per invokation), so the run time is `T(n) = T(n-1) + f(n)`, we only need to figure what `f(n)` is.

The bottle neck in each invokation is the `shift()` operation, which is iterating from `startA+1` to `startB`, meaning `n-1` iterations.

Thus, the complexity of the algorithm is `T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)`.

However, this is a known `Theta(n^2)` function ([sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)) - and the time **complexity of the algorithm is `Theta(N^2)`**, since the initial `startB-startA` is linear with `N` (the size of the input).

Comment: I see.But why is the runtime reduced only by `1`?The algorithm move 1 elements at each step (plus the shifting) and does this for **half** the elements (`N/2`) in total.Am I wrong on this?

Comment: @Cratylus: The algorithm as a function of `startB-startA` is reduced by 1 every iteration because the difference `startB-startA` is reduced by one, and the stop clause is when this difference is 0. Note that the `T(n)` is NOT in the terms of the size of the array, but in terms of `startB-startA`, now - assume `startB-startA == N/2` (Where `N` is the size of the array), it still gets you `Theta((N/2)^2) = Theta(N^2/4) = Theta(N^2)` solution.

Comment: Ah!My original intention is to do the check: `if(startB==a.length)return;` that is why I got confused with your point.Now I am not sure if algorithm is correct.I mean It eventually stop when the difference is `0` as you correctly point out, but how do I know that this is the correct thing to do?

Comment: @Cratylus: This is a different question, and you might want to post it as such. Though I don't think there will be any difference, as I see it (unless for some off by one error), the two suggested stop clauses should be identical, and the complexity remains the same.

Comment: I will post a different question for an alternative.For the runtime, your answer is very clear!Thank you!+1 by me